# Products always in stock - even when out of stock?

Tags: php, stock

So, after trawling through the internet for days and trying hundreds of fixes - i really can't understand why this is happening...

My store configuration is set to show out of stock items and i've enabled it so customers can sign up for updates, however when a product is out of stock it still shows Availability: In Stock on the frontend.

My default.phtml

```
<?php /* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract */?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra') ?>
<?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This only started happening recently (believe it was after an update (recently updated to 1.9.2.1

Any ideas?

Thannks

Comment: Is it for config product? and do you have easy switcher extension installed?

Comment: We do have easy switcher installed yes - and it happens on both config products and simple.

Comment: On simple products it doesn't show the add to cart but shows Availability: IN stock
On config products it shows both even if its out of stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is I believe because of extension `easylife switcher`.

In the configuration section of `easylife switcher` there is this setting `Show out of stock configurations`. Set that to `false` if you don't want the out of stock products displayed.

Check this: https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/issues/84

Comment: Amazing, can't believe it was that (atleast now I can blame the last developer) - I didn't install it! Haha!

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers.